# Rank users by people reached

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page, people-reached

I'd like to see who's the most helpful, in some ordered list, similar to the options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users).

Comment: That is only intended as a rough guide as to how many views their questions (and some answers) have had and doesn't mean that one user is more helpful than another.

Comment: Why the downvotes  ? He just wants to know if this is possible ...

Comment: Here you go http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/301740/people-reached-total

Comment: @JudeRosario I had a silly joke request in before my edit. It involved milliSkeets.

Comment: Ha ha .. just saw the joke. Excellent Answer (query) by @Spokey .. Would up vote if it were an answer too

Comment: @lumberhack I've posted it as a CW answer,  below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/301740/people-reached-total) is the query posted by [Spokey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2220391/spokey) in the comments.